# Read/Write JS file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, file

Trying to read/write an js file in swift. But has permission error. 
That's what i'm doing:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "settings", ofType: "js", inDirectory: "config/") {
    do {
        let content = try String(contentsOfFile: path)
        var subContent = content.split(separator: "\r\n")
        subContent[55] = """
        \nuurl: "https://xpto-example/xxx",
        """
        let finalContent = try String(subContent.flatMap({ (subtring) -> String in
            return String(subtring)
        }))
        try finalContent.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
    } catch {
        print("content error")
    }
}
```

How is the best way to achieve the objective?

I'm trying to copy the file from bundle to FileManager, this file in document directory is an js readable? will it be loaded in html or i have to do some things?

Comment: You cannot write into the application bundle. For good reasons the bundle is read-only. Mutable files are supposed to be located in the `Documents` folder

Comment: I've tried to locate this file using FileManager, but not found it... Some idea of how to find him?

Comment: You have to copy the file from the bundle into `Documents`.

Comment: And how i do? That are some ready method for this?

Comment: Yes, look into `FileManager`

Comment: But if the file was not found with FileManager, how i copy that from bundle?

Answer (score 0):

You have to restrict your write activities to your app's Documents folder, which not surprisingly, is the only place iOS allows your app write permissions.

Here's a sample View Controller which writes a string to disk (and which I just tested successfully):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]

    let mydoc = "testdocument"
    let filename = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("output.txt")
    do {
        try mydoc.write(to: filename, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to write!")
        fatalError()
    }
    print("saved!")
```

}

}

Successful Test:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to copy the bundle file to this directory, but it takes an error: "No such file or directory". How i can find the file before copy?